# React router and scrollToTop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Following documentation on [reacttraining](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration)

I use the following :

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

and

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <App />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

This works pretty well with desktop browser.

On mobile devices, the scrollTo does not work at all.

I tried to add `setTimeout` but this doesn't help.

I'm able to reproduce strange mobile behavior on desktop if I use the `scrollTo` with option `behavior: "smooth"`.

It does not scroll to the top at all or it scrolls randomly according to the sizes of the pages I'm coming from or going to.

In that case, using setTimeout fixes it on desktop but it is still broken on  mobile.

Any idea ?